# as3 center images horizontally

Tags: actionscript-3

with the formula below I can center one image horizontally.

```
 var xPoint= stage.stageWidth / 2 - imgWidth / 2;
```

In case if I may have more than one image, how can I center them horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to center them based on their total width. Assuming they all have the same width, something like that should work:

```
var imageX:int = (stage.stageWidth - images.length * imgWidth) / 2; // Assuming all the images have the same width

for (var i:int = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image:* = images[i];
    image.x = imageX;
    imageX += imgWidth;
}
```

If they have different width, just calculate the total width by looping through the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them all to a container and center the container instead:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(img1);
container.addChild(img2);
//...
container.x = (stage.stageWidth - container.width) * 0.5;
```